# WidgetKit @ObservableObject not updating view

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I'm having trouble understanding how to make my `SwiftUI` data model work with my Widget. It's working in my app just fine, changes happen immediately, but on my Widget (I'm using `WidgetKit`), no changes happen, and when debugging, it turns out my data is blank but it isn't! I'm using an `ObservableObject` class and `@Published` variables. I've attempted to use a `@StateObject`, `@ObservedObject` and an `@EnvironmentObject` but the result is always the same...

**SwiftUI App (working)**

```
@main
struct TrainlyApp: App {

    @StateObject var journeyBook = JourneyBook()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(journeys: $journeyBook.journeys).onAppear {
                JourneyBook.load { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .failure(let error):
                        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
                    case .success(let journey):
                        journeyBook.journeys = journey
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**WidgetKit (not working)**

```
struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {

    public typealias Entry = SimpleEntry

    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<SimpleEntry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
        let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 1, to: Date())!

        JourneyBook.load { result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
            case .success(let journey):
                entries.append(SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, configuration: configuration, journeys: journey))
            }
        }

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
    let journeys: [Journey]
}

struct TrainlyWidgetEntryView: View {

    var entry: Provider.Entry

    init(entry: Provider.Entry) {
        self.entry = entry
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("...")
    }
}

@main
struct TrainlyWidget: Widget {

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            TrainlyWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Next Train")
        .description("Live train status and countdown to your next journey.")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall])
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, they doesn't work with WidgetKit. You need read move about it limitations. There is Apples article about yours problem https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date

Comment: Then, how do I access my app's data? I need to get my Journeys in some way...

Comment: Widgets are like a gif and each entry is like a screenshot. All the data has to be injected in the get timeline method. To simulate a widgets behavior have all the views only use “let” properties. If you have new data to show you have to reload the timeline.

Comment: @loremipsum and how do I do that? Doesn't my timeline reloads every minute with my code?

Comment: No it doesn’t, I think it is a maximum of 70 times a day and apple can reduce that number at any time. Try the “widget code along” that apple has from one of its WWDCs it will talk about all the basics.

Comment: @loremipsum I watched all the "code along"s from WWDC but couldn't find anything to help me... My issue remains...

Comment: There is no way for anybody to help you here. You need to provide a minimal reproducible example in code in the question. Nobody is going to go to your pastebin for code but it sounds like you are just misunderstanding how widgets work. Like I said before make all your properties a “let” and reload your timeline when you need it reloaded. None of the wrappers work with a widget. All the data is given to the widget in the get timeline method.

Comment: @loremipsum fine I updated my post with the minimum code you need to get my issue

Comment: You are mixing asynchronous code and synchronous code. The last 2 lines in get timeline should be at the end of the success case. Right now they run before the body on the load runs

Comment: You need call `completion(timeline)` in the completion closure of `JourneyBook.load`.

Comment: @loremipsum it still doesn't work... For an unknown reason, the entry's journey is empty...

Comment: @Max094Reikeb WidgetKit works very differently, the views are serialised ahead of time, so your `@State`, `@ObservedObject` etc wouldn't work, think of them as pre-processed views. That is why you have the timeline provider, if anything changes in the widget refresh the widget so that timeline provider re-generates the views again